# How to use redis modules such as ft.search in aws elastic cache redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster, aws-cloud9, amazon-elasticache

We all know that AWS elastic cache provides two caching processes one is MEMECACHED and another one is REDIS .

So now I am using REDIS and want to use REDIS search module according to my requirement .How can I use it in AWS?

I have created REDIS cluster and connected to REDIS with the help of REDIS cluster URL .Now I want to use REDIS search. is there a way to use it in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot use RediSearch with Elasticache, you can use it, and other capabilities, with [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://redis.com/try-free/) on AWS.

Thanks,
Amiram.